# I can't see content-type: gzip in chrome response header

Tags: php, .htaccess, gzip, laravel-9

i'm trying to enable gzip on my Laravel 9 website, it's hosted on an apache server with cPanel.

I've also enabled files compression on cPanel and added this code to .htacess:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
   AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
   # For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
   BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
   BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
   BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

I also added a middleware with this code:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if (in_array('gzip', $request->getEncodings()) && function_exists('gzencode')) {
            $response->setContent(gzencode($response->getContent(), 9));
            $response->headers->add([
                'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',
                'X-Vapor-Base64-Encode' => 'True',
            ]);
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

any thoughts on this?

Comment: Request headers comes from sender, so if you do not see it, ensure you are sending them

Comment: i apologize, i meant response headers